# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color') error while implementing HighCharts in my xx.ts controller

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am first time trying to implement highcharts in my project. I don't have enough understanding around this. I have also seen few documentation which I also tried to follow but nothing works in my case.

I have multi series high charts where I am planning to implement `shared:true` to see both values. It was working without error before implementation of `shared:true`. But, When I introduced this, the error started coming.

Basically, I want to implement this so that I can see both value at any single tooltip. And to do that either I have to implement either 'shared:true' or 'split:true'. But in my case nothing is working.

I was also checking highchart documentation and it seems work for them but not in my case.
[this is what I was following](https://pi.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.shared)

Here is the error:

> > TChartController.ts:942 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color')
> > at Object.formatter (TChartController.ts:942:81)
> > at f.refresh (highstock.js:238:71)
> > at highcharts-theme.js:60:25 formatter @ TChartController.ts:942 f.refresh @ highstock.js:238 (anonymous) @ highcharts-theme.js:60
> > setTimeout (async) (anonymous) @ highcharts-theme.js:57 b. @
> > highstock.js:21 t.runPointActions @ highstock.js:270
> > t.onContainerMouseMove @ highstock.js:262

Here is my code:

```
tooltip: {
    getLabelOverride: this.allowAngularContentInTooltip,
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    
    formatter: function ()
    {
        const highchartsFormatterContext = this;
        const numItems = highchartsFormatterContext.y;
        const viewItemsFiltersForDataPoint = highchartsFormatterContext.point?.additionalData?.viewItemsFilters;
        
        self.setViewItemsFilters(numItems, viewItemsFiltersForDataPoint);
    
        if (self.viewItemsFilters?.seriesId && self.multipleSeriesFilters?.length)
        {
            const seriesFilters = self.multipleSeriesFilters.find(x => x.seriesId === self.viewItemsFilters.seriesId || x.SeriesId === self.viewItemsFilters.seriesId);

            if (seriesFilters)
            {
                const mergedFilters = { ...seriesFilters, ...self.viewItemsFilters };

                self.viewItemsFilters = mergedFilters;
            }
        }

        let tooltipHeader: string;

        if (highchartsFormatterContext.point?.additionalData?.tooltip)
        {
            tooltipHeader = highchartsFormatterContext.point?.additionalData?.tooltip;
        }
        else
        {
            const dateFormat = self.intervalUnit
                ? self.intervalTooltipDateFormats[self.intervalUnit]
                : 'month';

            tooltipHeader = Highcharts.dateFormat(dateFormat, highchartsFormatterContext.key);
        }

        let valueString = Highcharts.numberFormat(highchartsFormatterContext.y, 0);

        if (highchartsFormatterContext.series?.tooltipOptions?.valuePrefix)
        {
            valueString = `${highchartsFormatterContext.series.tooltipOptions.valuePrefix}${valueString}`;
        }
        if (highchartsFormatterContext.series?.tooltipOptions?.valueSuffix)
        {
            valueString = `${valueString}${highchartsFormatterContext.series.tooltipOptions.valueSuffix}`;
        }

        const headerHtml = `<span style="font-size:10px;">${tooltipHeader}</span><br />`;                   
        const pointHtml = `<span style="color:${highchartsFormatterContext.series.color}">\u25CF</span> ${highchartsFormatterContext.series.name}: <b>${valueString}</b><br/>`;

        const footerHtml = self.generateViewItemsButtonMarkup();
                        
        return `${headerHtml}${pointHtml}${footerHtml}`;
    },
    stickOnContact: true,
    style: {
        pointerEvents: 'auto'
    }
    
},
    
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        connectNulls: true,
        events: {
            click: (event) =>
            {
                const dataPointLinkedWidgetFilters = event.point?.additionalData?.linkedWidgetFilters;

                if (!dataPointLinkedWidgetFilters)
                {
                    return;
                }

                const filterType: FilterType = this.getFilterType();

                if (!filterType)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.sendLinkedWidgetFiltersData(
                    dataPointLinkedWidgetFilters,
                    filterType);
            }
        }
    

}
        }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please reproduce this problem in the online editor demo? You can start here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your code snippet, `highchartsFormatterContext.series` can be null/undefined

When that is the case, this will correclty throw an exception `highchartsFormatterContext.series.color`

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color')

To stop the error, change the usage with [null propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
const pointHtml = `<span style="color:${highchartsFormatterContext.series?.color}">\u25CF</span> ${highchartsFormatterContext.series?.name}: <b>${valueString}</b><br/>`;
```

Comment: I was getting color and name before but after implementing `shared:true`, it is giving me `undefined`. After changing based on your code, it is showing `0` even though it has value and says `undefined:0`. Also, it is not returing the whole `return ${headerHtml}${pointHtml}${footerHtml}`;`.it is missing `headerHtml` and `footerHtml`.

Comment: That is not the problem you have reported though. Your question is about the `Cannot read properties of undefined` error and this answers it... I advise you to raise a separated question focuses on the implementation of the package your are having difficulties with. It would also be a great idea to provide in your new question a minimal reproducible error with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)